# Fix php warning: Illegal offset type error

Tags: php

I'm getting "illegal offset type" error for every iteration of this code. Here's the code in case anyone can help:

```
if ( ! empty( $display_args['allowed_tags'] ) ) {
    $allowed_tags = [];

    foreach ( $display_args['allowed_tags'] as $tag ) {
        $allowed_tags[ $tag ] = array();
    }

    print_r($allowed_tags);
}
```

Any ideas. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post the **Complete and unadulterated** error message. Then indicate which line number in the error message is which line in the snippet of code you show us

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At some point of the iteration, `$tag` of `$allowed_tags[ $tag ]` is invalid for use as an array key.

For example, try executing:

```
<?php
$a[ array() ] = 'hello';
```

And you will get:

> Warning: Illegal offset type in {{filepath}} line 2

So, you cannot blindly use `$tag` like that.

---

**Update per comment:**

For debugging you can use [`is_scalar()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-scalar.php) to see if a value is valid for use as an array key:

```
if ( ! empty( $display_args['allowed_tags'] ) ) {
    $allowed_tags = [];

    foreach ( $display_args['allowed_tags'] as $tag ) {
        if( is_scalar( $tag ) ) {
            $allowed_tags[ $tag ] = array();
        }
        else {
            echo 'cannot use!';
            var_dump( $tag );
            echo '<br>';
        }
    }

    print_r($allowed_tags);
}
```

Comment: Along with this, using `!is_scalar($tag)` may help with debugging.